It is a good idea to put auth in TENANT_APPS in a multi-tenancy django app?
I'm preparing a multi-tenancy app with django. I need that a user only can access and manipulate the data of your own schema.
For exemple, if a have domain_a and domain_b, some users should only acess domain_a data and another users only can access domain_b data, and never both.
Cause this, I decide to put the auth apps inside tenant apps:
SHARED_APPS = (
    'django_tenants',
    'homecare_public',

)
TENANT_APPS = (
    'homecare',
    'account',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'django_seed',

    'drf_yasg',
)
INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]
TENANT_MODEL = 'homecare_public.Client'
TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL = 'homecare_public.Domain'

As you can see, things like 'django.contrib.admin' and 'django.contrib.auth' are inside tenant_apps.
I wanna isolate the schemas, where each one have their own users!
So my question is: is this a good idea?
